# Angular service worker unable to cache image on Firebase Storage, causes 504 (Gateway Timeout)

Tags: angular, firebase-storage, angular-service-worker

I can't get the angular service worker to cache images stored on Firebase Storage so that they are available in offline mode.

I'm using angular 7.2.0, running on localhost on a windows machine.

To reproduce, do the following.

1. Upload an image to Firebase Storage and make a note of the download URL.
2. Run the following in PowerShell

```
ng new my-project --service-worker
cd .\my-project\
ng add @angular/pwa --project my-project
```

3. Edit `src/app/app.component.html` to

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg">
<img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{firebase project}.appspot.com/o/{image}.jpg?alt=media&token={token}">
```

4. Add the following to `src/ngsw-config.json` after

```
    "dataGroups": [
      {
        "name": "photos",
        "urls": [
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/**/*.jpg*",
          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/**/*.jpg"
        ],
        "version": 1,
        "cacheConfig": {
          "maxSize": 1000,
          "maxAge": "10d",
          "timeout": "3s",
          "strategy": "performance"
        }
      }
    ]
```

5. Back in powershell, run:

```
ng build --prod
http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/my-project
```

6. Open `http://localhost:8080/` in Chrome and see the two images shown OK.
7. Turn off internet access or in DevTools, go offline.
8. Open `http://localhost:8080/` in Chrome. The wikimedia image is served by the service worker, but the firebase image is not shown.

I would expect both the wikimedia image and the firebase hosted image to have been cached by the service worker and shown, but only the wikimedia image has been cached. The Firebase one fails to load, giving a 504 Gateway Timeout error. See this image for what I see in my Chrome Dev Tools.

[image: DevTool showing the error I get]

Comment: Where you able to find a solution for this one?
My problem was there's a 504 gateway error from service worker.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue as well.  Not sure what the cause is

Comment: But I only see this IF i open dev tools.  Otherwise, no issues